# Use a checkbox to check other checkboxes in C#

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I wrote a code that enabled the use of checkbox with gridview, and it worked fine. I was afterward told to modify it, to enable a checkbox to check all. Please how do I go about it in C#. I have checked with Google and this site and cannot find any thing that can help my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use OnSelectedIndexChanged event.

Add your checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

In order to enable another checkbox you can use below code part.

```
 protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //anotherCheckbox.Checked = true;
 }
```

In order to check all items below code part can help you.

```
for(int i = 1; i < anotherCheckbox.Items.Count; i++)
{
     anotherCheckbox.SetItemChecked (i, true);
}
```

And you should call this loop from `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chkBox" runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="True"
                Text="check all"
                OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"/>
```

And

```
protected void Check_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (chkBox.Checked == true)
        {
          foreach (GridViewRow gvr in MyGridview.Rows)
          {
            //Programmatically access the CheckBox from the TemplateField
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("RowLevelCheckBox");
            //Check it!
            cb.Checked = true;
          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

loop through all rows in the gridview and set the value for the checkbox column to true.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[0].Value = true;
}
```

something like that.